# reindexing DB corruption?

Tags: magento2, database, magento2.3.4

I have been issues for a little while with my indexer not running.  I cleaned up most of the errors that I saw by running "bin/magento indexer:reindex" manually.  In that case, from googling around, it looked like there were some orphaned inno db files.  I moved them to a bak directory, and that cleared up those errors.

These were the apparent orphaned files.  I moved the to a backup folder in case I still need to recover them.

```
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 2.5K Apr  9 06:24 cataloginventory_stock_status_replica.frm
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 2.6K Apr  9 06:24 catalog_product_index_eav_replica.frm
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 2.8K Apr  9 06:24 catalog_product_index_price_replica.frm
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 160K Jun  4 09:24 design_config_grid_flat.ibd
```

After that, this is what the reindex command output looks like:

```
sw_temp@steamspeed:~/httpdocs$ php bin/magento indexer:reindex
Design Config Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Customer Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:01
Category Products indexer process unknown error:
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1932 Table 'www_steamspeed.catalog_category_product_index_store42_replica' doesn't exist in engine, query was: TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_product_index_store42_replica`
Product Categories indexer process unknown error:
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1932 Table 'www_steamspeed.catalog_category_product_index_store42_replica' doesn't exist in engine, query was: TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_product_index_store42_replica`
Catalog Rule Product index is locked by another reindex process. Skipping.
Table "catalog_product_index_eav_replica" does not exist
Table "cataloginventory_stock_status_replica" does not exist
Inventory index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Product Rule index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Table "catalog_product_index_price_replica" does not exist
Google Product Removal Feed index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Google Product Feed index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Search index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
```

So, that catalog_category_product_index_store42 table seems to be a problem.  The inno db files seem to be there, but perhaps they are corrupted?

This is what MySql says about its status:

```
Jun 13 22:04:05 steamspeed.com mysqld[26146]: 2020-06-13 22:04:05 7f46d7735700 InnoDB: cannot calculate statistics for table "www_steamspeed"."catalog_category_product_index_store42_replica" because the .ibd file is missing. For help, please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html
Jun 13 22:04:05 steamspeed.com mysqld[26146]: 2020-06-13 22:04:05 7f46d7735700 InnoDB: cannot calculate statistics for table "www_steamspeed"."catalog_category_product_index_store42_replica" because the .ibd file is missing. For help, please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html
Jun 13 22:04:05 steamspeed.com mysqld[26146]: 2020-06-13 22:04:05 7f46d7735700 InnoDB: cannot calculate statistics for table "www_steamspeed"."catalog_category_product_index_store42_replica" because the .ibd file is missing. For help, please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html
Jun 13 22:04:05 steamspeed.com mysqld[26146]: 2020-06-13 22:04:05 7f46d7735700 InnoDB: cannot calculate statistics for table "www_steamspeed"."catalog_category_product_index_store42_replica" because the .ibd file is missing. For help, please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html
Jun 13 22:04:05 steamspeed.com mysqld[26146]: 2020-06-13 22:04:05 7f46d7735700 InnoDB: cannot calculate statistics for table "www_steamspeed"."catalog_category_product_index_store42_replica" because the .ibd file is missing. For help, please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html
Jun 13 22:04:05 steamspeed.com mysqld[26146]: 2020-06-13 22:04:05 7f46da20e700 InnoDB: cannot calculate statistics for table "www_steamspeed"."catalog_category_product_index_store42_replica" because the .ibd file is missing. For help, please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html
Jun 13 22:04:05 steamspeed.com mysqld[26146]: 2020-06-13 22:04:05 7f46da20e700 InnoDB: cannot calculate statistics for table "www_steamspeed"."catalog_category_product_index_store42_replica" because the .ibd file is missing. For help, please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html
Jun 13 22:04:05 steamspeed.com mysqld[26146]: 2020-06-13 22:04:05 7f46da20e700 InnoDB: cannot calculate statistics for table "www_steamspeed"."catalog_category_product_index_store42_replica" because the .ibd file is missing. For help, please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html
Jun 13 22:04:06 steamspeed.com mysqld[26146]: 2020-06-13 22:04:06 7f46b77fb700 InnoDB: FTS Optimize Removing table www_steamspeed/catalogsearch_fulltext_scope42
Jun 13 22:04:06 steamspeed.com mysqld[26146]: 2020-06-13 22:04:06 7f46b77fb700 InnoDB: FTS Optimize Removing table www_steamspeed/catalogsearch_fulltext_scope43
```

But, the files appear to be there.

```
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql     2114 Jun 13 21:18 catalog_category_product_index_store42.frm
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql   131072 Jun 13 21:16 catalog_category_product_index_store42.ibd
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql     2114 Dec 29  2018 catalog_category_product_index_store42_replica.frm
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql    65536 Jun 13 21:18 catalog_category_product_index_store42_replica.ibd
```

What do I need to do to fix my corrupted files?

Comment: did you find any solution to this?